# Design Pattern to Add, Edit and Delete Records

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, crud

This code allows **Add, Edit and Delete** a database record for the `Category` table. Separate Service classes are implemented to handle these operations which are called via the Web API Endpoint `CategoriesController`.

- I want to improve the current code pattern because I am not sure calling `BaseBusinessService.Execute()` on `CategoriesController` is good practise?
- `Execute()` is declared as **Public** in the **Abstract Class** `BaseBusinessService`. I am not sure whether this is a good idea?

The following code with basic explanation.

**BaseController.cs** - to abstract the common tasks, such as store the connection string.

```
public class BaseController
{
    protected string DbConnectionString { get; }

    protected BaseController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        DbConnectionString = configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings:databaseConnectionString").Value;
    }
}
```

**CategoriesController.cs** - called via the api endpoint.

```
[Route("api/v1/categories")]
public class CategoriesController : BaseController
{
    public CategoriesController(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]CategoryModel model)
    {
        new CategoryAddService(DbConnectionString, model).Execute();

        return new OkResult();
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody]CategoryModel model)
    {
        new CategoryEditService(DbConnectionString, id, model).Execute();

        return new OkResult();
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        new CategoryDeleteService(DbConnectionString, id).Execute();

        return new OkResult();
    }
}
```

**BaseBusinessService.cs** - to abstract common methods, the implemented service classes must inherit from this class.

```
public abstract class BaseBusinessService
{
    protected string DbConnectionString { get; }

    protected BaseBusinessService(string dbConnectionString)
    {
        DbConnectionString = dbConnectionString;
    }

    protected abstract void OnValidate();
    protected abstract void OnExecute();

    // This method is called from the Controller, that's why this is Public. Not a good idea?
    public void Execute()
    {
        OnValidate();
        OnExecute();
    }
}
```

**CategoryAddService.cs** - Gets called from the Api Endpoint and adds a single record into the database.

```
public class CategoryAddService : BaseBusinessService
{
    CategoryModel _categoryModel;

    public CategoryAddService(string dbConnectionString, CategoryModel categoryModel) : base(dbConnectionString)
    {
        _categoryModel = categoryModel;
    }

    protected override void OnValidate()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnExecute()
    {
        var poco = PreparePoco(_categoryModel.CategoryName);

        AddCategoryRecord(poco);
    }

    CategoryPoco PreparePoco(string categoryName)
    {
        return new CategoryPoco()
        {
            CategoryName = categoryName
        };
    }

    void AddCategoryRecord(CategoryPoco poco)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(DbConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Insert(poco);
        }
    }
}
```

**CategoryEditService.cs** - Gets called from the api endoint, validates the existing record and updates the row in the database.

```
public class CategoryEditService : BaseBusinessService
{
    readonly string _categoryName;
    readonly int _id;

    public CategoryEditService(string dbConnectionString, int id, CategoryModel categoryModel) : base(dbConnectionString)
    {
        _categoryName = categoryModel.CategoryName;
        _id = id;
    }

    protected override void OnValidate()
    {
        // Validate and throw the error if the doesn't exists.
    }

    protected override void OnExecute()
    {
        var poco = PreparePoco(_categoryName);

        UpdateCategoryRecord(poco);
    }

    CategoryPoco PreparePoco(string categoryName)
    {
        return new CategoryPoco()
        {
            CategoryId = _id,
            CategoryName = categoryName
        };
    }

    void UpdateCategoryRecord(CategoryPoco poco)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(DbConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Update(poco);
        }
    }
}
```

**CategoryDeleteService.cs** - Gets called via the api endoing, validates the existing row and deletes a record from the database.

```
public class CategoryDeleteService : BaseBusinessService
{
    readonly int _id;

    public CategoryDeleteService(string dbConnectionString, int id) : base(dbConnectionString)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    protected override void OnValidate()
    {
        // Validate and throw the error if the doesn't exists.
    }

    protected override void OnExecute()
    {
        DeleteCategoryRecord();
    }

    void DeleteCategoryRecord()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(DbConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Delete<CategoryPoco>(_id);
        }
    }
}
```

**CategoryPoco.cs** - This is used for the Dapper and SimpleCRUD ORM.

```
using Dapper;
namespace AppPattern.Categories.Services
{
    [Table("Category")]
    public sealed class CategoryPoco
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CategoryModel.cs** - A model which does the *validation* using FluentValidation library.

```
using FluentValidation;
namespace AppPattern.Categories.Models
{
    public class CategoryModel
    {
        string _categoryName;
        public string CategoryName
        {
            get { return _categoryName; }
            set { _categoryName = value.Trim(); }
        }
    }

    class CategoryAddModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CategoryModel>
    {
        public CategoryAddModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.CategoryName).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.CategoryName).Length(1, 128)
                .When(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.CategoryName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered [using MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki)? You can [add validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283011/add-validation-to-a-mediatr-behavior-pipeline) using for instance [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation). Perhaps even consider a [CQRS flow](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/05/05/cqrs-with-mediatr-and-automapper/)?

Comment: @BCdotWEB I haven't heard about MediatR. But, am using the FluentValidation to validate the incoming data for the Model in the above example please refer to the `CategoryModel`. I will go through the articles you suggested.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Are you hinting that I can consider doing the validation for all the incoming data against the database in the `CategoryAddModelValidator` itself?

Comment: The problem with your code is that you still need to manually call the Validator and deal with the results etc. If you use MediatR, you could implement this in a more generic way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283011/add-validation-to-a-mediatr-behavior-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

**Dependency inversion principle violation**

`CategoriesController` depend on `Category[operation]Services` (concrete implementations) rather depending on abstractions.

How to prevent this rule violation? *Write unit tests*.

**Side note:** `BaseController` depend on concrete configuration value. But that value is used only in data access. So data access classes should depend on value, not controller itself.

**Pattern names should match implementations.**

What I mean is, that `Category[operation]Service`-s are not services at all. They are commands. So maybe you mean `CategoryEditCommand`, `CategoryDeleteCommand` and so on.

I will give you a more concrete example:

```
public interface ICategoryFactory {
    CategoryModel GetCategory();
}
```

Everyone expect that `Factory` should have `Create` method, not `Get`, `Set` or something else.

What we expect for service is like:

```
public interface ICategoryService
{
   CategoryModel GetCategory(int id);
   void AddCategory(CategoryModel model);
   void EditCategory(int id, CategoryModel model);
   void DeleteCategory(int id);
}
```

Using `Command` pattern here is overhead. `Command` pattern is commonly used for hiding how the command is executed and to provide comprehensive way of adding extensions.

**Suggestions**

So for your scenario I suggest:

1. Refactor your *services* to one `ICategoryService` that I have suggested above.
2. Make `CategoriesController` depend on `ICategoryService`.
3. Remove configuration value dependecy from `BaseController` and add it to implementation of `ICategoryService`

   Don't forget to register `ICategoryService` in your `IoC` container.

**Update 1:** About Validators. For separating concepts I would suggest following hierarchy:

**ICategoryStore** - nothing business related, just db operations.

```
public interface ICategoryStore
{
   CategoryModel GetCategory(int id);
   void AddCategory(CategoryModel model);
   void EditCategory(int id, CategoryModel model);
   void DeleteCategory(int id);
}
```

Based on how complex you can decide how higher should be your validation abstraction, I can suggest following:

**IValidator** - Encapsulates validation logic for entity.

```
public interface ICategoryValidator 
{
   void ValidateAdd(ModelState state);
   void ValidateEdit(ModelState state);
   void ValidateDelete(ModelState state);
}
```

And finally `ICategoryService` which implementation should depend on `ICategoryStore` and `ICategoryValidator`.

With this approach you can abstract higher, by introducing `IStore<T>` and `IValidator<T>`.

Comment: Combining Add, Edit, Delete and Get Methods in a single Interface and implement that in a single class can be quite a lot. Because the different set of validations will be implemented for Add, Edit and Delete. The class can become quite large. The Categories is just an example of a master data maintenance, but classes to handle Transactions such as Order, Quotations, etc could be quite large. Please let me know if am wrong?

Comment: @CoderAbsolute Please see Update 1.

Answer (score 0):

- A shallow answer: BaseBusinessService can be a class interface instead. you are not using its base implementation.
- A Deeper one : you can implement many interfaces in a class so you can put the method execute in its own interface and implement it once you need it.